# Translate relative layout and get the changed height in Android Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to translate the relative layout from bottom up and want to continuously get the changed height of the layout. What's the right way of doing?

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
animation.setDuration(333);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Right now, I am just using the above code but I don't know how to listen to the changed height.

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 1):

Use this library :[AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

it has listeners and nice animations, Highly reccommended

Example : [Refer](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/daimajia/androidanimations/ExampleActivity.java)

Using android own implemntaion

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to do it without using any third party library?